# problem accessing custom module in Anaconda3 path

Tags: python, anaconda

I have added a new_folder to C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages which contains an empty *_init_.py* and various custom modules (uncompiled python files). Scouring this site indicates I should now be able to generically call these custom modules in other python files. However, I keep on getting the ModuleNotFoundError when running these other programs. I am using Windows10. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

I am using *from module1 import function1* where function1 is contained in *C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\new_folder\module1*

Comment: How you try to import new modules? And show new modules schema please

Comment: Thx Nick. Now added

Comment: Have you tried from new_folder.module1 import function1 ?

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: You are welcome. IMO better to not manually copy something to site-package, but make your own package and install it via pip or conda install.